# Неожиданное поведение bash скрипта в части проверки кода возврата

Tags: bash

подскажите, пожалуйста. Есть утилита, которая в определенном случае возвращает код 70. Мой код по обработке такой ситуации не работает, в чем я неправ?

```
kesl-control --start-task 1 &> /dev/null
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    echo 1
elif [[ $? == 70 ]]; then
    echo 2
else
    echo 3
fi
```

По идее если код возврата 70, то мой скрипт должен выводить `2`, но он в таком случае всегда выводит `3`. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$? - это код завершения последней команды. Сначала он равен тому, что возвращает `kesl-control`. Следом выполняется проверка условия в if и $? становится другим - в зависимости от результата выполнения условия. Чтобы зафиксировать результат `kesl-control` и сделать несколько проверок именно по нему, нужно сразу присвоить его переменной. Например, так:

```
(exit 70)

result=$?

if [[ $result == 0 ]]; then
    echo 1
elif [[ $result == 70 ]]; then
    echo 2
else
    echo 3
fi
```

```
2
```

[Здесь подробно](https://ru.hexlet.io/blog/posts/kak-ispolzovat-kody-zaversheniya-v-bash-skriptah)

Проверить такое поведение можно таким простым образом:

```
(exit 45)

echo $?
echo $?
```

```
45
0
```

Сначала выводится код завершения (exit 45) - он равен 45, как и ожидалось. Но после вывода на экран команда echo возвращает код уже своего успешного завершения - 0, что и печатается во втором echo.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал использовать `case` это удобнее и выглядит лучше:

```
kesl-control --start-task 1 &> /dev/null
case $? in
     0) echo 1;;
    70) echo 2;;
     *) echo 3;;
esac
```